# sql date convert to string format

Tags: sql-server

How can I convert GETDATE() into a string like so: '2010-10-15'

-rod.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120)
```

By setting the `varchar` length, you can effectively truncate unwanted portions of the DateTime

**[CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)**

Answer (score 2):

Here a complext way to do it:

```
Select Convert(char(4),DATEPART(yy,GetDate())) + '-' + convert(char(2),DATEPART(mm,GetDate())) + '-' + Convert(char(2),DATEPART(dd,GetDate()))
```

An easier way is:

```
Select Convert(VARCHAR(10), GetDate(), 120)
```

You might want to take a look at the T-SQL Convert function. It allows you to format dates in many pre-defined ways:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below code which will convert your date for specific format

```
SELECT convert(varchar,Getdate(),23) -- YYYY-MM-DD
SELECT convert(varchar,Getdate(),105) -- DD-MM-YYYY
SELECT convert(varchar,Getdate(),110) --MM-DD-YYYY
```

Comment: 23 is not a documented option for convert, the others aren't what the OP asked for and the accepted answer from 2010 already has link for the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it, SELECT REPLACE(CONVERTrt(varchar(10),GETDATE(),111)'/','-')

Comment: it contains excessive 'rt' in CONVERTrt and missing virgule before '/'